# How best to display truncated links?

Tags: usability, hyperlinks, text, readability

I'm working on a Q&A platform, and I was wondering.

Within My Account you can check your questions, answers and comments such as

> [Your answer]
>
> Date: [XX-XX-XX] Number of answers:[XX]
>
> Related question: [Text of related question]

Since the question and answers can be pretty long, I'm thinking about shortening them to 140-170 characters. What I'm worried about, is how to display the fact that it has been shortened, as the text will be a link. Usually, links suchs as "Show more" are much more visible because the question/answer/comment text is not a link itself. What are some good option to show that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple and conventional way would be the ellipsis. CSS even has the property `text-overflow` which has ellipsis as an option.

http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

#### Example

[My short string](http://google.com)

[My longer string that will get cut ...](http://google.com)

[My other much longer string  tha...](http://google.com)

#### Working Example on UX Stackexchange

This technique is used right here on ux.stackexchange in the questions/answers section of the profile page. The usability is increased by offering the full text on hover via a tooltip.

[image]

#### Another Example on the Youtube Homepage

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I considered this as a viable option but was not totally convinved. I did not notice StackExchange and YouTube using this method.